# Delegate gets called but the calling viewcontroller is released

Tags: objective-c, delegates

Probably a noob question, but I cannot seem to get it right at the moment. I am working on an app where I have an Actionsheet for the confirmation of some basic things. However after the delegate is called for that Actionsheet my initial calling object is released (or not initiated).

In the delegate method I then want to call a method on that object but it just not do anything from that point.

The self.inviteSponsorsFromVC is not initiated anymore in this scenario and I want to call the saveSponsorWithEmail method from it. I cannot just reinitiate it, as the object had some objects in it, it has to use.

Everything works correctly if I just remove the actionsheet and call the saveSponsorWithEmail method directly without using a delegate.

This is my delegate method:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    //Get the name of the current pressed button
    NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if  ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"Send invitation", nil)]) {
        ContactFromAddressBook *contactFromAddressBook = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:selectedIndex.row];
        [self.inviteSponsorsFromVC saveSponsorWithEmail:contactFromAddressBook.email andName:contactFromAddressBook.fullName];        
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)]) {
        NSLog(@"Cancel pressed --> Cancel ActionSheet");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be the object you assign as a delegate is null at the time of assignment?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly, but my actionsheet has self as the delegate. I guess that creates a new instance of it, when the delegate method is called?

Comment: @Hugo Nope, invoking a delegate method does not create a new instance, it just calls the delegate method on the instance referenced by `self`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that at in the delegate method the content of `self.inviteSponsorsFromVC` is `nil`. In Objective-C, when you send a message to `nil` the message is simply ignored (unlike C++, for instance, where you get a crash when you call a method on a `NULL` object).

As an experiment you can try either one of these:

- If you use ARC, make the property `self.inviteSponsorsFromVC` a strong reference
- If you don't use ARC, say `[self.inviteSponsorsFromVC retain]` at some point before you display the action sheet

Either way, what you need to do is to make sure that the object in `self.inviteSponsorsFromVC` is not deallocated before you invoke a method in it.

---

**EDIT** after your comment

The property declaration is good, it's got the `strong` attribute on it. In your `InviteSponsorsFrom` class, try to add a `dealloc` method and set a breakpoint there to see if the object is deallocated, and where the call comes from.

```
- (void) dealloc
{
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Also make sure that an instance of `InviteSponsorsFrom` is created in the first place. I assume you have an initializer somewhere in that class where you can set a breakpoint and/or add an `NSLog` statement to make sure that the instance is created.

Comment: The property is declared like this at the moment:
`@property (nonatomic, strong) InviteSponsorsFrom *inviteSponsorsFromVC;`
I think I need to do something more here?

Comment: @Hugo I've updated my answer. I'm not sure if you are notified by the edit, so I'm poking you with this comment :-)